# Integers represented by the polynomial

Tags: number-theory

Can every sufficiently large integer be written in the form $a^{100} + b^{101} + c^{102} + d^{103} + e^{104}$ for some non-negative integers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and $e$? I'm only 15 so if u could please write as elemntary as you can! I know that this problem can be solved elementary :)

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not possible.  Given a large integer $N$, there are $N^{\frac 1{100}}$ smaller numbers of the form $a^{100}$.  There are even fewer of the forms with higher exponents.  This means you can express less than $(N^{\frac 1{100}})^5=N^{\frac 1{20}} \lt N$ numbers this way.

Comment: Hey, i don't really get it why are there there are $N^{\frac 1{100}}$ smaller numbers of the form $a^{100}$ and why there are even fewer of the forms with higher exponents :(

Comment: @user51650:   Let's use squares.  Given a large $N$, how many integers of the form $a^2$ are less than $N$?.  We must have $a^2 \lt N,$ or $a \lt \sqrt N$.  Then if you ask for cubes, it is the cube root of $N$.  The argument is the same with higher exponents.

Comment: @user51650:  My argument and Thomas Andrews' are essentially the same.  He is more careful than I was about the boundary conditions.  In the square example, there are 11 numbers less than 101 of the form a^2 (a can range from 1 through 10), while my square root would give 10.

Comment: Then if you ask for cubes, it is the cube root of N - i dont get it :( ?

Comment: @user51650:  How many cubes are less than $1000?$  It is 10(OK-11, if you use less than or equal), which is the cube root of 1000.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A=\{n\in\mathbb N: \exists a,b,c,d,e\in\mathbb N: n= a^{100}+b^{101}+c^{102}+d^{103}+e^{104}\}$.  For $N>0$, let $A_N=\{n<N: n\in A\}$.

If your statement were true, we'd have, amongst other things, that $\lim_{N\to\infty} |A_N|/N =1$.

Now 
write $n=1+\lfloor\sqrt[100]N\rfloor$. Then the set of $5$-tuples $(a,b,c,d,e)$ such that $a^{100}+b^{101}+c^{102}+d^{103}+e^{104}<N$ is at most $n^5$.  Therefore, $$|A_N|<(1+\lfloor \sqrt[100]N\rfloor)^5$$

I think it is therefore pretty obvious that $|A_N|/N\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$.

This is a much stronger result than negating your result - it says that $|A_N|=O(\sqrt[20]N)$, which is a very sparse set.